# Replace "BasicHttpParams"

Tags: android, http

I am making a register/login page for my android app but the code I am trying to use is deprecated. Does anyone know a replacement? My code is below, the second to last line is the deprecated code. `BasicHttpParams();`

```
public class ServerRequests {
ProgressDialog progressDialog;
public static final int CONNECTION_TIMEOUT = 15000;
public static final String SERVER_ADDRESS = "http://telarad.com/";

public ServerRequests(Context context)
{
    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
    progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
    progressDialog.setTitle("Working on it...");
    progressDialog.setMessage("Connection InterFace is getting your account ready.");
}

public void storeDataInBackground(Contact contact, GetUserCallback callback)
{
    progressDialog.show();
}

public void fetchDataInBackground(Contact contact, GetUserCallback callback)
{
    progressDialog.show();
}

public class StoreDataAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
{
    Contact contact;
    GetUserCallback callback;

    public StoreDataAsyncTask(Contact contact, GetUserCallback callback)
    {
        this.contact = contact;
        this.callback = callback;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put("Email", contact.email);
        values.put("Username", contact.username);
        values.put("Password", contact.password);

        HttpParams httpRequestParams = new BasicHttpParams();

        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: use volley http://www.truiton.com/2015/02/android-volley-example/

Comment: Volley is best replacement for your problem.. and also more efficient

Comment: You can use retrofit for api calls..

Comment: I have put volley in gradle but that line of code is still unsupported.

Comment: I have never used retrofit, how do I use it?